# Can't re-install MySQL on OS X Leopard after uninstalling

Tags: macos, mysql, osx-leopard

I'm running Leopard (10.5.8) on a Macbook (not Pro) and I had MySQL running ok, but the Preferences pane wasn't working. I thought a fresh install would be a good idea, so I went through the uninstall process described here:

- [How to remove MySQL completely Mac OS X Leopard](http://tomkeur.net/39/how-to-remove-mysql-completely-mac-os-x-leopard.html)
- [How do you uninstall MySQL from Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436425/how-do-you-uninstall-mysql-from-mac-os-x)

... which consisted of removing a bunch of files like this:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*
vim /etc/hostconfig and removed the line MYSQLCOM=-YES-
rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/My*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
```

But now when I try and install `mysql-5.5.20-osx10.5-x86.pkg`

I get this:

> The following install step failed run postflight script for mysql 5.5.20-community for Mac OS X. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.

mysql is there, after each failed install, but all my attempts to use it get the same error msg:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
dyld: unknown required load command 0x80000022
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

In the first link you referenced, there was one command missing, Ben Alpert answered with this reply.

```
$ sudo rm -rf /var/db/receipts/com.mysql.*
```