# Can't install MySQL on Mountain Lion

Tags: mysql, osx-mountain-lion

I have clean 10.8 OS X (with Retina MacBook Pro).

I have totally the same situation like here
[Can't re-install MySQL on OS X Leopard after uninstalling](https://superuser.com/questions/383215/cant-re-install-mysql-on-os-x-leopard-after-uninstalling)

and similar with that
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067787/re-install-mysql-in-mac-os-x-10-6-6

But in last case I have user mysql already.

When I'm trying to install it from package, i see in syslog next message

```
    Aug 22 08:08:29 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Aug 22 08:08:29 nnn-laptop.local CoreServicesUIAgent[317]: Error: qtn_file_apply_to_path error: Read-only file system
Aug 22 08:08:29 nnn-laptop.local Installer[315]: CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in environment to log backtraces.
Aug 22 08:08:53 --- last message repeated 3 times ---
Aug 22 08:08:53 nnn-laptop.local authorizationhost[323]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Got user: nnn
Aug 22 08:08:53 nnn-laptop.local authorizationhost[323]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Got ruser: (null)
Aug 22 08:08:53 nnn-laptop.local authorizationhost[323]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Got service: authorization
Aug 22 08:08:53 nnn-laptop.local authorizationhost[323]: in od_principal_for_user(): No authentication authority returned
Aug 22 08:08:53 nnn-laptop.local authorizationhost[323]: in od_principal_for_user(): failed: 7
Aug 22 08:08:53 nnn-laptop.local authorizationhost[323]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Failed to determine Kerberos principal name.
Aug 22 08:08:53 nnn-laptop.local authorizationhost[323]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Done cleanup3
Aug 22 08:08:53 nnn-laptop.local authorizationhost[323]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Kerberos 5 refuses you
Aug 22 08:08:53 nnn-laptop.local authorizationhost[323]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): pam_sm_authenticate: ntlm
Aug 22 08:08:53 nnn-laptop.local authorizationhost[323]: in pam_sm_acct_mgmt(): OpenDirectory - Membership cache TTL set to 1800.
Aug 22 08:08:53 nnn-laptop.local authorizationhost[323]: in od_record_check_pwpolicy(): retval: 0
Aug 22 08:08:53 nnn-laptop.local authorizationhost[323]: in od_record_attribute_create_cfstring(): returned 2 attributes for dsAttrTypeStandard:AuthenticationAuthority
Aug 22 08:08:53 nnn-laptop.local authorizationhost[323]: in pam_sm_setcred(): Establishing credentials
Aug 22 08:08:53 nnn-laptop.local authorizationhost[323]: in pam_sm_setcred(): Got user: nnn
Aug 22 08:08:53 nnn-laptop.local authorizationhost[323]: in pam_sm_setcred(): Context initialised
Aug 22 08:08:53 nnn-laptop.local authorizationhost[323]: in pam_sm_setcred(): Got euid, egid: 0 0
Aug 22 08:08:53 nnn-laptop.local authorizationhost[323]: in pam_sm_setcred(): Done getpwnam()
Aug 22 08:08:53 nnn-laptop.local authorizationhost[323]: in pam_sm_setcred(): Done setegid() & seteuid()
Aug 22 08:08:53 nnn-laptop.local authorizationhost[323]: in pam_sm_setcred(): pam_sm_setcred: krb5 user nnn doesn't have a principal
Aug 22 08:08:53 nnn-laptop.local authorizationhost[323]: in pam_sm_setcred(): Done cleanup3
Aug 22 08:08:53 nnn-laptop.local authorizationhost[323]: in pam_sm_setcred(): Done seteuid() & setegid()
Aug 22 08:08:53 nnn-laptop.local authorizationhost[323]: in pam_sm_setcred(): Done cleanup4
Aug 22 08:08:53 nnn-laptop.local authorizationhost[323]: in pam_sm_setcred(): pam_sm_setcred: ntlm
Aug 22 08:08:53 nnn-laptop.local authorizationhost[323]: in pam_sm_setcred(): pam_sm_setcred: no domain found skipping
Aug 22 08:08:53 nnn-laptop.local com.apple.SecurityServer[15]: UID 501 authenticated as user nnn (UID 501) for right 'system.install.software'
Aug 22 08:08:53 nnn-laptop.local com.apple.SecurityServer[15]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.install.software' by client '/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Install.framework/Versions/A/Resources/runner' [321] for authorization created by '/System/Library/CoreServices/Installer.app' [315] (100003,0)
Aug 22 08:08:53 nnn-laptop.local coreservicesd[33]: Application App:"Установщик" [ 0x0/0x34034]  @ 0x0x7fcdfad21b70 tried to be brought forward, but isn't in fPermittedFrontASNs ( ( ASN:0x0-0x36036:) ), so denying.
Aug 22 08:08:53 nnn-laptop.local WindowServer[77]: [cps/setfront] Failed setting the front application to Установщик, psn 0x0-0x34034, securitySessionID=0x186a6, err=-13066
Aug 22 08:08:53 nnn-laptop.local com.apple.SecurityServer[15]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.install.apple-software' by client '/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PackageKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/installd' [324] for authorization created by '/System/Library/CoreServices/Installer.app' [315] (4,0)
Aug 22 08:08:53 nnn-laptop.local com.apple.SecurityServer[15]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.install.software' by client '/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PackageKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/installd' [324] for authorization created by '/System/Library/CoreServices/Installer.app' [315] (4,0)
Aug 22 08:08:57 nnn-laptop.local com.apple.SecurityServer[15]: Succeeded authorizing right 'com.apple.ServiceManagement.daemons.modify' by client '/usr/libexec/UserEventAgent' [11] for authorization created by '/usr/libexec/UserEventAgent' [11] (100012,0)
Aug 22 08:08:57 nnn-laptop.local installd[330]: *** NSTask: Task create for path '/Volumes/mysql-5.5.27-osx10.6-x86_64/mysql-5.5.27-osx10.6-x86_64.pkg/Contents/Resources/preflight' failed: 22, "Invalid argument".  Terminating temporary process.
Aug 22 08:08:57 nnn-laptop kernel[0]: exec of /Volumes/mysql-5.5.27-osx10.6-x86_64/mysql-5.5.27-osx10.6-x86_64.pkg/Contents/Resources/preflight denied since it was quarantined by Safari and created without user consent, qtn-flags was 0x00000006
Aug 22 08:08:57 nnn-laptop.local ReportCrash[331]: DebugSymbols was unable to start a spotlight query: spotlight is not responding or disabled.
Aug 22 08:08:57 nnn-laptop.local ReportCrash[331]: failed looking up LS service ( scCreateSystemService returned MACH_PORT_NULL, called from SetupCoreApplicationServicesCommunicationPort, so using client-side NULL calls.
Aug 22 08:08:57 nnn-laptop.local ReportCrash[331]: LaunchServices/5123589: Unable to lookup coreservices session port for session 0x186a0 uid=0 euid=0
Aug 22 08:08:57 nnn-laptop.local ReportCrash[331]: failed looking up LS service ( scCreateSystemService returned MACH_PORT_NULL, called from SetupCoreApplicationServicesCommunicationPort, so using client-side NULL calls.
Aug 22 08:08:57 nnn-laptop.local ReportCrash[331]: LaunchServices/5123589: Unable to lookup coreservices session port for session 0x186a0 uid=0 euid=0
Aug 22 08:08:57 nnn-laptop.local ReportCrash[331]: failed looking up LS service ( scCreateSystemService returned MACH_PORT_NULL, called from SetupCoreApplicationServicesCommunicationPort, so using client-side NULL calls.
Aug 22 08:08:57 nnn-laptop.local ReportCrash[331]: LaunchServices/5123589: Unable to lookup coreservices session port for session 0x186a0 uid=0 euid=0
Aug 22 08:08:57 nnn-laptop.local ReportCrash[331]: failed looking up LS service ( scCreateSystemService returned MACH_PORT_NULL, called from SetupCoreApplicationServicesCommunicationPort, so using client-side NULL calls.
Aug 22 08:08:57 nnn-laptop.local ReportCrash[331]: LaunchServices/5123589: Unable to lookup coreservices session port for session 0x186a0 uid=0 euid=0
Aug 22 08:08:57 nnn-laptop.local ReportCrash[331]: failed looking up LS service ( scCreateSystemService returned MACH_PORT_NULL, called from SetupCoreApplicationServicesCommunicationPort, so using client-side NULL calls.
Aug 22 08:08:57 nnn-laptop.local ReportCrash[331]: LaunchServices/5123589: Unable to lookup coreservices session port for session 0x186a0 uid=0 euid=0
Aug 22 08:08:57 nnn-laptop.local ReportCrash[331]: Saved crash report for installd[330] version 241 to /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/installd_2012-08-22-080857_nnn-laptop.crash
Aug 22 08:08:58 nnn-laptop.local com.apple.SecurityServer[15]: Succeeded authorizing right 'com.apple.ServiceManagement.daemons.modify' by client '/usr/libexec/UserEventAgent' [11] for authorization created by '/usr/libexec/UserEventAgent' [11] (100012,0)
Aug 22 08:08:58 nnn-laptop.local Installer[315]: CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in environment to log backtraces.
Aug 22 08:08:58 nnn-laptop.local Installer[315]: Установщик обнаружил ошибку, вызвавшую сбой установки. Обратитесь за помощью к производителю ПО.
```

Seems to me problem in that place

```
Aug 22 08:08:57 nnn-laptop.local installd[330]: *** NSTask: Task create for path '/Volumes/mysql-5.5.27-osx10.6-x86_64/mysql-5.5.27-osx10.6-x86_64.pkg/Contents/Resources/preflight' failed: 22, "Invalid argument".  Terminating temporary process.
```

But content of preflight is:

```
#!/bin/sh
# 
# preflight - this script will be executed before the MySQL PKG
# installation will be performed.
#   
# If this package has been compiled with a prefix ending with "mysql" (e.g.
# /usr/local/mysql or /opt/mysql), it will rename any previously existing
# directory with this name before installing the new package (which includes
# a symlink named "mysql", pointing to the newly installed directory, which
# is named mysql-<version>)
#

PREFIX="/usr/local/mysql"
BASENAME=`basename $PREFIX`

if [ -d $PREFIX -a ! -L $PREFIX -a $BASENAME = "mysql" ] ; then
        mv $PREFIX $PREFIX.bak
fi
```

The last line is 18, there is no any 22nd line.

Comment: As solution i've used lower version 5.1.65  and it works well

Answer (score 1):

It appears this error is related the Apple's quarantine of downloaded applications. Usually it presents a dialog, but when it can't, it prevents the app from launching.

The indicative line is:

```
Aug 22 08:08:57 nnn-laptop kernel[0]: exec of /Volumes/mysql-5.5.27-osx10.6-x86_64/mysql-5.5.27-osx10.6-x86_64.pkg/Contents/Resources/preflight denied since it was quarantined by Safari and created without user consent, qtn-flags was 0x00000006
```

You could try copying the package out of the disk image, and then running `xattr -dr mysql-5.5.27-osx10.6-x86_64.pkg` on the package. See [this post](http://rsbox2.heliohost.org/wordpress/?cat=15) for more details.